# Jquery stop function from being called in a particular scenario (when its already being called by other event)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm trying to call a function in 2 ways: either way, when the function is called it should not allow the other one to call the method

Here `renameFolder` is called in 2 places: first on focus out and second when enter is being pressed.

The problem is that when enter is pressed it calls the function 2 times 1 for enter being pressed and second for focus out as well.

```js
$('#rename').click(function() {

  //delete previous popup-menu if exists
  removeMenu();

  var folder = e.target.id;
  var folderId = $("#" + folder).attr("id");
  var folderName = $('#' + folder).parent().parent().children('.bd-title').text().trim();

  $('#' + folder).parent().parent().children('.bd-title').replaceWith('<textarea class="bd-folder-title-input" oninput="this.style.height = `1px`;this.style.height = (10+this.scrollHeight)+`px`;"  onfocusout="renameFolder()" maxlength="50" cols="10">' + folderName + '</textarea>');
  $('textarea').focus();
  $('textarea').select();
  $("textarea").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
      renameFolder();
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Couldn't you instead of renaming the folder just blur the text area when the enter key is pressed? That way only the bluring will handle the renaming of the folder.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML to make a [mcve]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tzx0ojLk/12/ this is the example reproduced. kindly have a look.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible method, one easy way would just be to funnel everything through one path:

```
$("textarea").keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
    $(e.currentTarget).trigger('focusout'); // or blur
  }
});
```

Comment: yes its a very good approach but it didnt work in my case i tried triggering focusout but it doesnt do anything neither gives any error than i tried focus on something else as a workaround that didnt work either. following is js fiddle example for better understanding. https://jsfiddle.net/tzx0ojLk/12/